# MassTransit AzureServiceBus generated queues

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azureservicebus, masstransit

I have a working configuration for a MT setup that is hosted in an Azure Service Fabric solution.

I have an API that sends messages and a stateless app that reads them.

Inside the stateless app I tell it to consume messages of type `TestMessage` with the following:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IConsumer>());
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
        {
            var h = cfg.Host(new Uri("sb://xxxxx.servicebus.windows.net"), host =>
            {
                host.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

                host.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey", "******");
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(h, "fabric-test", ec =>
            {
                ec.UseMessageScope<ConsumeContext>();
                ec.LoadFrom(_container);
            });
        });
```

And in the API I am specifying the fabric-test queue and sending with:

```
var p = await _bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("sb://xxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/fabric-test"));

await p.Send(new TestMessage(Guid.NewGuid()));
```

And that all works great - however.

When i look a the azure portal I can see that 3 queues have been created and 1 topic:

- desktopmmd2jga_stateless1_bus_qypoyyypboqbzhk5bdkg665cyh (queue)
- desktopmmd2jga_webapi1_bus_qypoyyypboqbsitfbdkg665pdd (queue)
- fabric-test (queue)
- xxxxx.core.testmessage (topic)

While it all does *work* I am wondering what all this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stateless1` is your service fabric bus instance, the temporary queue created for that bus.
`webapi1` is your web api bus instance, which is used to send to the stateless service, also a temporary queue.
`fabric-test` is your service queue for your receive endpoint.
`namespace.core.testmessage` is your message type, which is subscribed to by your service endpoint.

This is all built by MassTransit, to support the message structure you're using. The temporary queues disappear after 5 minutes, no worries there - they're just for addressing and maintaining the connection to ASB.

The topic is created in the event a message is *published* of that type, so that your service endpoint receives it. If you don't want to subscribe topics for message types for a particular service endpoint you can specify `SubscribeMessageTopics = false` in the configuration for that endpoint.`