# MassTransit temporary queue pile up

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

(See also [MassTransit AzureServiceBus generated queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901571/masstransit-azureservicebus-generated-queues))

I'm configuring a bus with the following using MassTransit 4.0 with AzureServiceBus for transport:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
{
    IServiceBusHost host = cfg.Host(
        BusHostUri,
        hostCfg =>
        {
            hostCfg.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(
                KeyName,
                SharedAccessKey);
        });

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, QueueName, e =>
    {
        e.Consumer<ValueEnteredConsumer>();
    });
});
```

When run it creates:

- A queue matching `QueueName`
- A topic matching the message type from the consumer
- A subscription under that topic matching `QueueName` and forwarding messages to that queue
- A queue named something in the form of:

  `{machine}_{application}_bus_{26 random letters}`

The first three seem fine.  However for that last item, the temporary queue I believe, each restart triggers a newly created queue.  From Service Bus Explorer it appears that the queue has AutoDeleteOnIdle set 427 days.

What do I need to do to allow/require the temporary queues to be deleted within a more reasonable time window (e.g., 10 days)?  And, if possible, to have the application that created it also delete it during shutdown.

Comment: This is a bug in 4.0, which has been fixed and should be released as 4.0.1 soon.

Comment: This is resolved and 4.0.1 was released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Chris Patterson for the quick confirmation.  The recent change that seems related:

- [Issue #1045](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1045)
- [Commit c7faad7e5ec33179a51aca9c89769ba0cfc2df05](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/commit/c7faad7e5ec33179a51aca9c89769ba0cfc2df05)